# Diagflow @sys.number-integer cannot remove colon? Assistant hears 130 as 1:30

Tags: actions-on-google, diagflow

When I voice to google assistant "Set temperature to one thirty", it hears "Set temperature to 1:30"

When this is mapped to an entity @sys.temperature it is unresolved and reprompted, and will then hear "130", yet still reprompts.

When it is mapped to @sys.number-integer it resolves to "1".

How can I make it hear "one thirty" as an integer or at least be smart enough to convert it? Do I have to do a synonym for every possible number?

Comment: Are you saying "one thirty" or "one hundred thirty"?

Comment: "one thirty". After it reprompts it later understands "one thirty" as "130", but not initially.

Comment: You can file a bug/enhancement for the same.